# javascript - Accessing this in the then part of a promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, es6-promise, nativescript-vue

My component has a data property `daily_goal`.

I have a modal that is used to set a new value to `daily_goal`.

I open my modal like so:

```
  toSetDailyGoalPopup() {
    this.$showModal(setDailyGoalPopup, {
      fullscreen: true,
      props: {daily_goal: this.daily_goal},
    }).then(function(newGoal) {
      alert(newGoal);
      alert(this.daily_goal);
      this.daily_goal = newGoal;
    });
  },
```

And I close my modal like this:

```
<button
  text="Set"
  @tap="modal.close(daily_goal)"
/>
```

When I press set in my modal. The modal is closed, then I get **only one** alert correctly telling me the new value that is supposed to be set, but the second alert is not displayed and the value is also not updated.

How can I change this code to achieve what I want?

**Update**
The following did the trick:

```
.then(
  ((newGoal) => {this.daily_goal = newGoal;}).bind(this)
)
```

Comment: @Bergi I tried `}).then(this.callback.bind(this));` and defined the function as a method but it didn't work, can you elaborate please?

Comment: There's no reason to define the function as a method. Just use an arrow function, or your function expression with `.bind(this)` at the end.

Comment: @Bergi maybe you could show me how exactly I should do that. I don't know what you exactly mean by function expression of an arrow function

Comment: I said function expression (`.then(function(newGoal) { … }.bind(this))`) *or* arrow function (`.then(newGoal => { … })`)

Comment: Regarding your update, using *either* `bind` *or* arrow function syntax is enough. Don't use both together.

Comment: oh! yeah, I get it now!